# not getting inside while loop when selecting a single row from sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I have a problem with `sqlite`, when i select a **single row** from **table** and then check `sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW` both values are different and not getting inside `while statement`.

**This is the code:**

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    //NSLog(@"working777.............%d",sqlite3_step(statement));

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
       NSLog(@"working888.............%d",SQLITE_ROW);
       NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc]   initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];


       NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc]    initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];


       NSLog(@"............statement...........addressField %@, phoneField %@",addressField,phoneField);
    } 

   sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
   sqlite3_close(db);

 }
```

Comment: You need to post the query. The while loop will only be entered if there is one or more results from the query. If the query returns no rows then the while loop will not be entered.

Comment: NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Major_Events WHERE temple_id =\"%@\"", temp_id]; this is the query that i used and there is a row in the table corresponding to that temp_id

Comment: String values should be single-quotes, not double-quotes. Is the temple_id column in the table text or a number? Only use the quotes if it's text. It's also bad form to create SQL statements like this. You really should bind the variable instead of using string formats.

Comment: temp_id is a number...can u post me the qurey for select...

Comment: NSLog your quesry then copy it and paste it in`sqlite manager` then execute your query and see does your query execute correctly or not ....

Comment: temp_id is a number...can u post me the qurey for select...

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to create such a query would be like this:

```
NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT * FROM Major_Events WHERE temple_id = ?";
```

Then prepare the statement. I assume query_stmt is the char * value from querySQL.

Once the statement is prepared you then need to bind the value.

```
sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, temp_id); // bind is 1-based
```

Of course temp_id needs to be an int value and not a string. There are various sqlite3_bind_xxx statements for different data types. Use the appropriate one.

Once all of the query parameters are bound, you can execute the query using sqlite3_step.

The nice thing about this approach over string formats is that strings get properly escape and put in quotes for you. It's much harder to mess up and it makes your queries much safer against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

For many records:-

```
if (sqlite3_open([[self getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sql = "select * from Place";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            }
            sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
             sqlite3_close(database);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

If you want a single record then change while to if

if(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
```

rest everything will be same

I hope it helps and if your while loop is not getting executed then it means there is some problem with your query.You need to check that also.